# sliding div contents

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking for some good tutorials and like for learning how I'd apply the following effect to my site. I've got a `div`with text in it. I'd like to be able to press a button to slide the text so that it's no longer viewable then press it again to expand the div to view the contents inside. does anyone know of some good tutorials that would enable me to achieve the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a tutorial, look at this one:
http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/jquery-tutorials-for-designers/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [**`.slideToggle()`**](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) method in jQuery

Answer (score 1):

you can use this with jquery:

```
<div id="yourid"> Your content</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#yourid').toggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```